# How can I do multiple calculations with one result in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 EditBoxes with the respective values: Runway Heading Wind Direction Wind speed for that I have to use the formula with the respective values. First I have to calculate

Crosswind component = sin(wind direction - runway heading) * wind speed

But I dont know how to implement this...

Comment: So... where are you stuck?

Comment: How can I put this formula into a code?
I tried that:

                    rwy_hdg.getText().toString();
                    wind_drc.getText().toString();
                    wind_kts.getText().toString();
                    double a1=Double.valueOf(rwy_hdg.getText().toString());
                    double a2=Double.valueOf(wind_drc.getText().toString());
                    double a3=Double.valueOf(wind_kts.getText().toString());
However, I do not know how to do several calculations with one result.

Comment: Hi there, By do several calculations with one result, do you mean to calculate some thing based on value change in either of the boxes?

Comment: Please provide additional information to your problem.
Description (how) with Result (is) and what you would want (expectation)

Comment: hi, I have 3 EditBoxes with the respective values:

Runway Heading
Wind Direction
Wind speed

for that I have to use the formula with the respective values.
First I have to calculate

Crosswind component = sin(wind direction - runway heading) * wind speed


I calculate with 3 values each several times and I do not know how I should implement this

Comment: What is the problem, really? You have three EditTexts. Add a button for calculation. In the button handler read the latest values and do the math. You'll find the `sin()` function in Java's `Math` object.

Comment: ok, i tried to help you a bit. feel free to improve it as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'm gonna try to help you with something off the bat here. But you'll probably need to adapt it a bit.

```
EditText windDirectionEditText;
EditText runwayHeadingEditText;
EditText windSpeedEditText;
Button calculate;
TextView crossWindResultTextView;

public onCreate() {
   //assign the views to their correponding fields
   windDirectionEditText = findViewById(R.id.wind_direction);
   runwayHeadingEditText = findViewById(R.id.runway_heading);
   windSpeedEditText = findViewById(R.id.wind_speed);
   calculate = findViewById(R.id.calculate_stuff);
   crossWindResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.crosswind_text);

   // assign the clicklistener to button so that when clicked, it calculates stuff and put it's result in the result text view
   calculate.setOnClickListener( click -> {
       // gather values
       double windDirection = Double.valueOf(windDirectionEditText.getText().toString());
       double windSpeed = Double.valueOf(windSpeedEditText.getText().toString());
       double runwayHeading = Double.valueOf(runwayHeadingEditText.getText().toString());
       // calculate stuff
       // Crosswind component = sin(wind direction - runway heading) * wind speed
       double crosswind = Math.sin(windDirection - runwayHeading) * windSpeed;

       // assign result to textview
       crossWindResultTextView.setText(crosswind + " kts");
    });
}
```

Now, you'll need a layout, you said you have 3 edit texts for the wind direction, runway heading and wind speed.

Put a textview somewhere in there, and a button.

Change this code so that their identifiers match the ones from the layout.

When you click the "calculate" button, the result textview will say whatever knots for the entered values.

Feel free to work from there and improve it as you need.

Comment: no problem, you're welcome. Technically, this isn't a real answer, and i'm gonna skip the obligatory "stackoverflow is not a code writing service" comments - and just focus on "are you sure it works alright and makes correct calculations?" because this seems to be used with airplanes, and a bug in there could have.... very bad life-threatening outcomes. Please test thoroughly before using it "in production" :)

Comment: The Code is working correctly. And no, im not using this for work or something like that.
It was just a project for some math calculations.
Regards :)